# Water tower hydro generator?

Tags: pressure, energy-conservation, velocity, water, fluid-statics

$500$ gallons, $100$ feet high, at tank $10$ inch pipe, every $4$ feet a reduction of $2$ inch pipe diameter, ending in $1/4$ inch tubing to jet nozzles, each nozzle would spin an independent generator with tesla coil style wraps (tight first layer one direction, looser wrap opposite direction).

Would the pressure increase and addition of multiple generators displace the cost of pumping the $100+$ feet back to the tank?

We can also have the system precharged on return line, to a couple inches from fill. This would create extra head pressure to pump against though.

If someone has the mathematical skills to calculate I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Are you asking if you can generate energy for nothing? If, so the answer is "No."

Comment: Can you give a diagram?

Comment: I'll sketch a diagram up.

Comment: Not free energy, just small scale system that can translate into a more efficient large scale, possibly hydro dams/recirculation facilities.

Comment: Large scale versions already exist. E.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seneca_Pumped_Storage_Generating_Station